# Present Simple or Present Continuous with "these days"

Tags: present-continuous, present-simple, progressive-aspect

[image]

"**These days**" express the period around now. Then, I wonder, why is used the Present Simple in the following sentence?:

- These days I **travel** a lot.  I’m spending more and more time away from
  home. (Considering the rule given above, I would say: These days I **am travelling** a lot.)

I've also come across the sentence where both  tenses are considered correct:

- These days, more and more people **prefer / are preferring** to
  retire    early.

So, is it optional whether we use present simple or continuous with "**these days**"?

Comment: Yes it's optional. Both are correct. **Prefer** says in one word what **are preferring** says in two and brevity is a virtue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The present simple can *also* refer to things in the period around 'now'.

It can be used for statements of general truth ("the sky is blue") or for conditions that pertain ("I know how to change a lightbulb"). When used with an adverbial of time, they might also be used for statements of general truth ("in the morning, I prefer not to speak to people") and provide for a condition as part of that statement. However, an adverbial of time can also accompany a statement of current conditions ("right now, I am hungry"), *provided that the adverbial of time involved includes 'now'*.

The progressive aspect refers to ongoing or recurring actions, and so can also be used for things that are located in time around now. "I am travelling a lot these days" is essentially equivalent to "I travel a lot these days". A key point that must be understood about English is that ***there is not always only one verb form/tense/mood/aspect that is correct***.

***Preferring*** is a somewhat special case, though. It is rarely used in the progressive aspect. Indeed, I'm racking my brain for cases of use of the *-ing* form at all, and mostly it's used in various adverbials.

> "They were offered the choice of pinot noir or pinot grigio. Preferring red wine, Susan chose the pinot noir."

(I'm not actually sure if it's being a gerund or a participle in that case)

Comment: Here's an unusual example of *preferring* in gerund form: *Preferring red wine in these situations is always cost effective.*

Comment: I'm not sure if that wouldn't be closer to the sense of 'prefer' seen in "preferring charges", though it's semantics that leads me to that conclusion rather than grammar.

Comment: I think you mean "*proffering* charges."

Comment: Sense 2 here: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/prefer

Comment: Sense 5 there: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prefer

Comment: You beat me to it. I was just about to make a different comment . . . I find that really bizarre. I have never heard anybody use it in that sense before. In any case, it's not really relevant to the gerund discussion.